# How do I maintain focus position in UpdatePanel after page partial post back

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have four controls in a page with update panel.  Initially mouse focus is set to first control.  When I partially post back the page to server the focus automatically moves to first control from the last focused control from the control I have tabbed down to.  Is there any way to maintain the last focus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [Restoring Lost Focus in the Update Panel with Auto Post-Back Controls](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/restoring-lost-focus-in-update-panel.html):

> The basic idea behind the solution is to save the ID of the control
>   with input focus before the update panel is updated and set input
>   focus back to that control after the update panel is updated.
>
> I come with the following JavaScript which restores the lost focus in
>   the update panel.
>
> ```
> var lastFocusedControlId = "";
>
> function focusHandler(e) {
>     document.activeElement = e.originalTarget;
> }
>
> function appInit() {
>     if (typeof(window.addEventListener) !== "undefined") {
>         window.addEventListener("focus", focusHandler, true);
>     }
>     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(pageLoadingHandler);
>     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoadedHandler);
> }
>
> function pageLoadingHandler(sender, args) {
>     lastFocusedControlId = typeof(document.activeElement) === "undefined" 
>         ? "" : document.activeElement.id;
> }
>
> function focusControl(targetControl) {
>     if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer) {
>         var focusTarget = targetControl;
>         if (focusTarget && (typeof(focusTarget.contentEditable) !== "undefined")) {
>             oldContentEditableSetting = focusTarget.contentEditable;
>             focusTarget.contentEditable = false;
>         }
>         else {
>             focusTarget = null;
>         }
>         targetControl.focus();
>         if (focusTarget) {
>             focusTarget.contentEditable = oldContentEditableSetting;
>         }
>     }
>     else {
>         targetControl.focus();
>     }
> }
>
> function pageLoadedHandler(sender, args) {
>     if (typeof(lastFocusedControlId) !== "undefined" && lastFocusedControlId != "") {
>         var newFocused = $get(lastFocusedControlId);
>         if (newFocused) {
>             focusControl(newFocused);
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> Sys.Application.add_init(appInit);
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I find this more elegant:

```
    (function(){
    var focusElement;
    function restoreFocus(){
        if(focusElement){
            if(focusElement.id){
                $('#'+focusElement.id).focus();
            } else {
                $(focusElement).focus();
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('focusin', function(objectData){
            focusElement = objectData.currentTarget.activeElement;
        });
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(restoreFocus);
    });
})();
```