# TextChange event loose focus in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I am trying a very simple thing. I have 3 textboxes and 3 labels. On text change i am setting the content of label.

The issue is when i insert some value in 1st textbox(e.g 50) change the focus to another textbox the values in label is reflected perfectly.
But the focus which i setted on 2nd textbox is lost. And the focus is lost somewhere. 
I need to click again on 2nd textbox to get focus.

The same issue is reproduced if TAB is clicked to change focus.

I have made a small demo project for the same and attached. You can avail that from the below link

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=A716D678775EEF95!115&authkey=!ABp6kAon_ZNDLBU

Please someone help me...what am i doing wrong??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather common issue in ASP.NET, as described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17571/Maintain-focus-between-postbacks-in-ASP-NET-2-0-al or here: [How do I maintain focus position in UpdatePanel after page partial post back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703079/how-do-i-maintain-focus-postition-after-page-partial-post-back). Those links also contain some suggestion on how to solve this issue.

One of the possible solutions is to keep track of control with focus, put information about it into a hidden field and manually restore the focus after postback. This method is described in the first link mentioned.

Comment: Hey thanks for your instant help. I just did ScriptManager1.SetFocus(TextBox2); on Text change event of TextBox1. And it worked....Thanks a ton..... :)

Comment: If You want to set a focus on a specific control, You can also use `Focus()` method (for example write `TextBox2.Focus();` to set focus on `TextBox2` control), without calling the `ScriptManager`.